# FTP: Creating Nested Directories Automatically

Tags: ftp, automation, directory

We are trying to move a file to an FTP site. We need to create a folder structure like this:

> /deeply/nested/folder/structure/index.html

Yesterday, we realized we can't create more than one folder at a time, so this doesn't work:

> MKD /deeply/nested/folder/structure

So, in code, we wrote a loop that created each folder, one at a time, ignoring errors caused by the folder already existing. Ignoring errors is gross.

Is a way to create these nested folders in one action, rather than multiple? Is there a command to see if a folder already exists? If we just push the file out including the full path, will FTP be smart enough to create the directories for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no standard way to create a folder with subfolders. There's also no standard way to check if *directory* exists. You would need to use LIST or MLSD (where supported) and parse the result for this. Can't you just use some third-party component that supports the needed functionality?

Comment: LIST and NLST can cause a timeout rather than cause an immediate failure. They work fine whenever the directory actually exists.

Comment: Part of the problem is that we are receiving FTP information from our clients. We have no idea what FTP server they are using. Personally, I think we are tackling the wrong problem and need to think about alternatives to FTP, in general. However, this a fairly standard (if not poor) approach to loading HTML pages cross-site. Things like S3 simply may not be an option.

Comment: @TravisParks Badly written server can cause anything. Commands alone can't cause anything. As for alternative, take a look at SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple C# example here, maybe someone will need this code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace Deployer
{
    public class RecursiveFolderUploader
    {
        private const string SrcFullPath = @"C:\prg\Snowinmars\Snowinmars.Ui";
        private readonly IList<string> foldersOnServer;
        private Client ftpClient; // that's your ftp client, init it

        public RecursiveFolderUploader()
        {
            this.foldersOnServer = new List<string>();
        }

        private void UploadAll(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
        {
            // ftp://login:password@127.0.0.1/path/to/root/mydir/anotherdir/file.dat
            // ^________________uri_______________________^_relevationPath_^
            foreach (var file in directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles())
            {
                if (!file.Directory.FullName.StartsWith(RecursiveFolderUploader.SrcFullPath))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"File {file.FullName} is not from {RecursiveFolderUploader.SrcFullPath} folder");
                }

                string relevationPath; // all folders from root up to file

                if (file.Directory.FullName.Length == RecursiveFolderUploader.SrcFullPath.Length)
                {
                    relevationPath = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    relevationPath = file.Directory.FullName.Substring(RecursiveFolderUploader.SrcFullPath.Length, file.Directory.FullName.Length - RecursiveFolderUploader.SrcFullPath.Length);

                    if (relevationPath.StartsWith("\\"))
                    {
                        relevationPath = relevationPath.Remove(0, 1);
                    }
                }

                string destination;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(relevationPath))
                {
                    destination = file.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    destination = Path.Combine(relevationPath, file.Name).Replace("\\", "/");
                }

                try
                {
                    ftpClient.UploadFile(file.FullName, destination);
                }
                catch (WebException e)
                {
                    // that means that there's no such folder or something else goes wrong
                    // we can check it by creating folders and try again
                    var parts = relevationPath.Replace("\\", "/").Split('/');

                    for (int i = 1; i <= parts.Length; i++)
                    {
                        var path = string.Join("/", parts.Take(i));

                        if (!foldersOnServer.Contains(path))
                        {
                            ftpClient.MakeDirectory(path);
                            foldersOnServer.Add(path);
                        }
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        ftpClient.UploadFile(file.FullName, destination);
                    }
                    catch (Exception innerE)
                    {
                        // if it doesn't help - trouble isn't in folders
                        throw new WebException($"Can't find folder {relevationPath}", innerE);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories())
            {
                UploadAll(directory);
            }
        }
    }
}
```